# Filter file based on file format and midfix in bashscript

Tags: bash

I have following files in parent dir:

```
parent_dir/subdir0/subdir1/file1.txt.gz
parent_dir/subdir0/subdir1/file2.abc.txt.gz
parent_dir/subdir0/subdir1/file3.xyz.csv.gz
```

I would like to filter files based on format only. here formats are txt, csv etc...so if I provide format only i.e. midfix is empty then it should filter and print files which have matching format and empty midfix.

For e.g. if I provide `format="txt" and midfix=""` then should print `file1.txt.gz` Likewise, if I provide `format="txt" and midfix="abc"` then it should print `file2.abc.txt.gz`

I would even like to execute delete command to delete such filtered files.
Could you please provide sample code in bash for this?

Comment: I don't know what a _midfix_ is (found only [this](https://www.midfix.co.uk/), but could it be that you are simply looking for the [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) of those pathes, which end in `${format}.gz`?

Comment: consider: `for f in 'parent_dir/subdir0/subdir1/file1.txt.gz' 'parent_dir/subdir0/subdir1/file3.xyz.csv.gz'; do IFS=. read -ra s <<<"$(basename "$f" .gz)"; echo "${#s[*]}:${s[-1]}"; done`

Comment: @user1934428 , let's take below files for example: file1.txt.gz and file2.abc.txt.gz , so in case of file1 midfix is empty and format is "txt" , whereas for file2 , midfix is "abc"  and format is "txt". I just like to filter files using midfix and format. So if user provide midfix="" and format="txt" then my script should print file1.txt.gz . And if user provide midfix="abc" and format="txt" then program should print file2.abc.txt.gz

Comment: So in other words, you are interested in files of the form `X.${midfix}.${format}.gz`, with non-empty X. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could define:

```
filter()(
    shopt -s extglob globstar nullglob
    local f=$format m=$midfix t=$top
    [[ $f ]] || exit
    for q in "$t"/**/+([!.])"${m:+".$m"}.$f"?(.+([!.])); do
        "${@:-echo}" "$q"
    done
)
```

[Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) has full explanation of the individual commands. The more interesting sections are probably [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) and [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Then:

```
$ tree parent_dir
parent_dir
└── subdir0
    └── subdir1
        ├── file1.txt.gz
        ├── file2.abc.txt.gz
        └── file3.xyz.csv.gz

2 directories, 3 files
$ format=txt midfix= top=parent_dir filter basename
file1.txt.gz
$ format=txt midfix=abc top=parent_dir filter basename
file2.abc.txt.gz
$
```

To delete, you can replace `basename` with `rm --` (or the name of another bash function you write if you need something more sophisticated).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to filter files is to use "find". Find provides many additional filtering capabilities - in particular - using REGEXP instead of patterns, and adding options like synlink following, modtime checks, etc.

In the example below, it's used to filter out "real" files - excluding any directory that might have name that matches the pattern.

In few cases, this may result in improved performance.

```
# Using $parent, $mid and $format - as per SO

# Match folder, and prefix
re='./*[^/]*'
[ "$mid" ] && re+=".$mid"
re+=".$format"
re+='\(.[a-z0-9]+\)?'

# Just print the files
find "$parent" -type f -regex "$re"

# Or remove, or something else
find "$parent" -type f -regex "$re" | xargs rm -f --
```

Note: Answer retyped, hope no typo